# Edit already sent embed bot message discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to edit an embed message that has already been sent (serves as a role reaction message). For example: I type "roles" and get an embed message that assigns roles when reacted to. I want to edit it to add another role in the description without sending an entirely new message. MEE6 bot is able to this so I'm sure it's possible. I found code that should work:

```
# This sends an embed message with a description of the roles.
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id == 700895165665247325:
        if message.content.startswith('roles'):
            embedvar = discord.Embed(title="React to this message to get your roles!",
                                     description="Click the corresponding emoji to receive your role.\n<:WarThunder:"
                                                 "745425772944162907> - War Thunder\n<:Apex:745425965764575312> - "
                                                 "Apex\n<:ModernWarfare:757104623738814554> - "
                                                 "Modern Warfare\n<:Minecraft:757029546632413346> - "
                                                 "Minecraft\n<:R6Siege:757030019909550122> - R6 Siege", color=0x00ff00)
            embedvar2 = discord.Embed(title="React to this message to get your roles!",
                                      description="Click the corresponding emoji to receive your role.\n<:WarThunder:"
                                                  "745425772944162907> - War Thunder\n<:Apex:745425965764575312> - "
                                                  "Apex\n<:ModernWarfare:757104623738814554> - "
                                                  "Modern Warfare\n<:Minecraft:757029546632413346> - "
                                                  "Minecraft\n<:R6Siege:757030019909550122> - R6 Siege\n"
                                                  "<:AmongUs:760192601625591859> - Among Us", color=0x00ff00)
            await message.channel.send(embed=embedvar)
            await message.edit(embed=embedvar2)
            print("Changed message embed color.")
    else:
        return
```

Yet it gives me this error:

```
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50005): Cannot edit a message authored by another user
```

Yes, the bot has all the correct permissions and is assigning ranks lower on the hierarchy than it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the working code:

```
# This sends an embed message with a description of the roles.
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id == 700895165665247325:
        if message.content.startswith('roles'):
            embedvar = discord.Embed(title="React to this message to get your roles!",
                                     description="Click the corresponding emoji to receive your role.\n<:WarThunder:"
                                                 "745425772944162907> - War Thunder\n<:Apex:745425965764575312> - "
                                                 "Apex\n<:ModernWarfare:757104623738814554> - "
                                                 "Modern Warfare\n<:Minecraft:757029546632413346> - "
                                                 "Minecraft\n<:R6Siege:757030019909550122> - R6 Siege", color=0x00ff00)
            await message.channel.send(embed=embedvar)
            print("Changed message embed color.")
        elif message.content.startswith('update'):
            embedvar2 = discord.Embed(title="React to this message to get your roles!",
                                      description="Click the corresponding emoji to receive your role.\n<:WarThunder:"
                                                  "745425772944162907> - War Thunder\n<:Apex:745425965764575312> - "
                                                  "Apex\n<:ModernWarfare:757104623738814554> - "
                                                  "Modern Warfare\n<:Minecraft:757029546632413346> - "
                                                  "Minecraft\n<:R6Siege:757030019909550122> - R6 Siege\n"
                                                  "<:AmongUs:760192601625591859> - Among Us", color=0x00ff00)
            channel = client.get_channel(700895165665247325)
            msg = await channel.fetch_message(757114312413151272)
            await msg.edit(embed=embedvar2)
            print("Updated role reaction message.")
    else:
        return
```

I simply type "update" into the correct channel and whatever is in `embedvar2` is what the message is updated with.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to edit the `message` that was passed by the event, try:

```
msg = await message.channel.send(embed=embedvar)
await msg.edit(embed=embedvar2)
```

Comment: The problem is I still have to send "roles" in the channel to get the edited embed message.  How can I edit the one that is already there? Otherwise, this worked and sent a new message that said "edited"

Comment: You mean you want to edit this message when someone reacts to it? Do you have an `on_reaction_add` event?

Comment: Yes I do. After playing around I added another command to update the message and it works.  Thanks for your help!